# How can I fix this issue, when file download in the browser, it change encoding in file, I used Spring boot

Tags: spring

I used it code for response Excel byte[] to browser. But I have problem, because Spring boot encode file, and I got bad file than download from browser.

```
    //This method returned response on controller
    public  ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> 
    returnAllTransactionAsExcel(TransactionSearchFilter 
    transactionSearchFilter) throws IOException {
    List<Transaction> transactions = 
    getAllTransactions(transactionSearchFilter);
    byte[] ourFile=writeIntoExcel(transactions);

    //headers
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; 
    filename=list_transactions.xls");
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"));

    return
        ResponseEntity
        .ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentLength(ourFile.length)
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
        .body(new ByteArrayResource(ourFile));
    }

    //This method on controller
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retrieve all transactions in Excel")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allExcel", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    produces "application/vnd.ms-excel")
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> 
    getAllTransactionsAsExcel(@RequestBody TransactionSearchFilter 
    transactionSearchFilter) throws IOException {        
    return returnAllTransactionAsExcel(transactionSearchFilter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, all problem was in swagger-ui
https://github.com/webanno/webanno/issues/459